# How to make Groups or Hierarchies in TreeView of c# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, treeview, wpf-controls

I want to create Groups in my TreeView using code behind currently there is a flat hierarchy in TreeView, any idea how to do it?

Note: not using XAML as the TreeView is created at runtime

Comment: Post your code , how are you defining hierarchies?

Comment: like town names are in the TreeView using TreeView.items.Add but i want to make groups of countring and those group are parent node of towns

Comment: How to apply the Hierarchial Template to Tree View

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dudes here is the answer, ENJOY!
http://zamjad.wordpress.com/2009/12/06/using-hierarchical-data-template-with-c-code/#comment-446

Answer (score 0):

You can use HierarchicalDataTemplate where you can specify ItemsSource(=children). See here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd759035(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: did'nt get anything, sorry for my ignorance but i want the binding to happen using code behind  i have :-                               Binding bind = new Binding();
bind.Source = ?;//What should be here?
arrayTreeView.SetBinding(TreeView.ItemsSourceProperty, bind);